# Set Title tag inside shell script

Tags: html, shell, tags, title

I have an HTML snippet inside of which I have a `<title>` tag. I want that title to change every month when I generate a report. I can do that manually every month but I want to do this in such a way that it will automatically change title and to which month report it is.

How can I set a string inside the html `<title>` tag using a shell script to make sure the string is clearly unique?

Comment: What the heck are you talking about?

Comment: i have a html snippet inside which i have title tag.. i want that title to change every month when i generate report.. i can do that manually every month but i want to do sth that it will automatically change title and say which month report it is...

Answer (score 0):

Use [`uuidgen`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/uuidgen).

From the `man` page:

> The uuidgen program creates a new universally unique identifier (UUID) using the libuuid(3) library. The new UUID can reasonably be considered unique among all UUIDs created on the local system, and among UUIDs created on other systems in the past and in the future.